# Load PNG Images into .Rmd

Tags: r, pdf, png, r-markdown

I'm almost certian the solution for this is painfully simple, but I'm not sure how to load a PNG image, saved in an image folder in the same working directory, into the Rmd file that I'm working with. I just need the image to show up in the result Knitted PDF.

Comment: in your markdown, add : `![Caption for the picture.](/path/to/image.png)`

Comment: Thanks jeremy! I suppose I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @jeremycg, I tried the code you gave me and it gives me the following error: Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse
Execution halted

Comment: don't include it in a code block, just in the normal markdown where text is

Comment: Ah. Well, embarrassingly simple once again. Thanks for all your help!